# Possibility of non-intersecting chord diagrams with given sets of endpoints

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, geometry, discrete-geometry

Consider two finite subsets of a circle, $A,B \in S^1$, each with even number of elements. I want to construct two chord diagrams, one with endpoints set $A$,  and one with endpoints set $B$ in such a way that no two chords of different diagrams intersect.

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on sets $A$ and $B$ for this to be possible?

For example, it is impossible if there is an odd number of points from set $A$ between any two adjacent points of set $B$, or vice versa, but this seems like a too strong condition.

It seems like a problem that is obvious for someone knowledgeable in combinatorics and/or discrete geometry, but the full answer eludes me.

Comment: Isn't your necessary condition also sufficient? If there's an even number of points of $A$ between two adjacent points of $B$, you can connect them in adjacent pairs, similarly for an even number of points of $B$ between successive points of $A$.

Comment: It is sufficient, but too strong. There are many examples of configurations not satisfying this condition where non intersecting diagram can be built. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You could iteratively remove even sets, then adjacent segments of the other set merge and may become even, and so on. If you can remove all points then a non-intersecting diagram can be built.